# JavaScript constructs equivalent to eval()

Tags: javascript, reflection, eval

In JavaScript, `eval()` takes a string and executes it as JavaScript code, e.g.,

```
eval( "alert('I am parsed as JavaScript code.');");
```

I am interested in what constructs out there, other than `eval()`, can potentially be used for the same purpose. I know `eval()` is evil. This is for educational purposes.

So far I have found three such constructs:

1. The `Function` constructor:

   ```
   var f = new Function( "alert('I am also parsed as JavaScript code.');");
   f();
   ```
2. The `setTimeout()` function:

   ```
   setTimeout( "alert('So am I.');", 0);
   ```
3. The `setInterval()` function:

   ```
   setInterval( "alert('Me too!');", 0);
   ```

Are there other constructs that can be used to achieve this behavior? If yes, which ones? If no, any good references to substantiate that claim?

Comment: Those "constructs" use eval internally, and that's why they shouldn't be used like that either.

Comment: @A1rPun Yes, this is educational. In fact, I want to know what kind of constructs I should be wary of.

Comment: You got me wondering too :) +1

Comment: document.write can execute arbitrary code

Answer (score 3):

Sort of obscure, but so long as the page hasn't finished loading yet...

```
document.body.setAttribute("onLoad","alert('Hello world!');");
```

Not that anyone would do that. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Any function constructor will do:

```js
console.log.constructor("alert(\"hello\")")()
```

or

```js
(c=>Function(c))("alert (\"hello again\")")()
```

or

```js
(_=>_('alert("hello")'))(Array.constructor)()
```

or

```js
document.body.setAttribute("onmousemove","this.onmousemove=null;alert('hello')");
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body width="100%" hoight="100%">
hello
</body>
</html>
```

[image]